# Why isn't vector.clear() working while in a loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an application to calculate multiplicative persistence, like in this video: https://youtu.be/Wim9WJeDTHQ?t=197.

However my problem is that it does not appear that my vector is being cleared during iterations of the while loop. Which means the output produced is growing exponentially instead of working down to 0.

I am very new to coding c++ so any feedback would be appreciated.

```
std::vector<int> per;
int input;
int result;
int new_total = 1;
int loop_total;

std::cin >> input;

//Moving the user input into a vector

while (input > 0)
{
    result = input % 10;
    input = input / 10;

    per.push_back(result);
}

//loops to multiply new sets of numbers together until "new_total" is 0

while (new_total > 0) {

    for (int i = per.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        new_total = new_total * per[i];
    }

    per.clear();

    std::cout << "\n" << new_total << "\n";

    loop_total = new_total;

    while (loop_total > 0)
    {
        result = loop_total % 10;
        loop_total = loop_total / 10;

        per.push_back(result);
    }
}
```

I expected for the vector to be cleared each time so that the new sets of numbers were moved into the vector to be multiplied.

However the previous set of numbers appeared to remain present in the vector.

Comment: Print `per.size()` after `per.clear()` which would show you that `vector::clear` is working as expected but there is something wrong with your logic.

Comment: But you don't reset `new_total` value.

Comment: We generally expect code examples to be self-contained, i.e. enabling us to copy, paste, compile, run, and see the exact results you are seeing (ideally *without* requiring manual input). Your example is missing a surrounding `int main()` and includes; it's also relying on manual input. A really *good* question would include observed output, and *expected* output, so we can double-check those as well. (Quite often, the *expectation* is wrong, not the code itself.)

Comment: You probably want to set `new_total = 1;` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: `per.clear();  std::cout << "\n" << new_total << "\n"` -- The second line that you're using to determine if `per.clear()` works correctly is totally useless for that task.  It uses nothing of the `per` class whatsoever.  If anything, you should be using `per.size()` to determine if `per` is being cleared, and not rely on an extraneous variable such as `new_total`.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? At which lines did you expect the vector to be cleared?

Comment: `new_total ` is the product of all the elements  that ever existed in `per`. You can't tell anything about the current state of `per` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone. The solution to my problem was fixed by setting new_total=1; at the beginning of the while loop which makes sense as before new_value was being continually multiplied into.

Thanks for all the help :)